# Are the beta Stack Exchange site logos generated automatically?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, design

This is a pretty silly question, but nevertheless it's something that has been on my mind and so I figure I might as well ask.

The alignment of "Beta" with the stack exchange site name(e.g. "Gaming") is remarkably similar between all the different stack exchange sites, leading me to wonder: are the logos in these beta stack exchange sites generated automatically, or is each logo created in a program(such as Photoshop)?

Comment: It's very very likely done by hand. The number of sites is small, and there may be the need subtle differences in the positioning.

Comment: Jon Skeet does them in MS Paint, but he is a robot.

Comment: Awesome. If you put that as an answer I'll accept it, unless it was a joke.

Comment: @Peter: wrong.  Jon Skeet does them in a hex editor.

Comment: @Peter @squillman: I was under the impression that [Jon Skeet sets the universal constants at the start such that the universe evolves to contain the disk with the images he wants.](http://xkcd.com/378/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously I don't have any inside knowledge, but I'd be pretty certain they'd be done by hand. There's only a small number of sites and as Pekka points out in a comment above, some have differences in positioning (for example the [photography site](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) logo is split across two lines).

Doing it this way would be pretty trivial given that the scribbled text is actually [just a font](http://www.dafont.com/sketch-block.font?nb_ppp=50), so it would simply be a matter of opening up an existing logo template (with the layers/text intact), changing the text, repositioning a little if necessary & exporting as a `.png`.